# OOP in Lua From C

Tags: c++, c, oop, lua

I would like to implement Object Orientated Programming in my lua interpreter, I understand that I can return a lua table from a C Function. And I would like the table that is returned to be full of C functions.

```
player = getClosestPlayer();
player.walkTo();
```

where both getClosestPlayer() and walkTo() are C functions.

From the C function for walkTo(), how do I differentiate between object types?

I would prefer every object to have a gid that I can use to identify it (player.gid) but how do I access that gid from the c function?

In other words, what is the equivalent of self.gid from C code?

```
int l_playerWalkTo(lua_State* functionState){
    int gid = // self.gid?
    // do something with gid
}
```

One way I could do this is to upvalue every single function in the table, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to macroland for his answer, I just though I would clear up what he has said.
This lua wrapper can be used to implement c++ classes into Lua:
https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper/overview

A great example of the usage of this library can be found here:
https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapperexample/src/

Here is the code (taken straight from the example site)

Lua:

```
alicesaccount = BankAccount.new("Alice", 100)

alicesaccount:deposit(20);
alicesaccount:deposit(30);
alicesaccount:deposit(40);
```

c++:

```
BankAccount* BankAccount_new(lua_State *L)
{
    const char* owner = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    float balance = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
    return new BankAccount(owner, balance);
}

int BankAccount_deposit(lua_State *L)
{
    BankAccount* account = luaW_check<BankAccount>(L, 1);
    float amount = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
    account->deposit(amount);
    return 0;
}

static luaL_Reg BankAccount_table[] =
{
    { NULL, NULL }
};

static luaL_Reg BankAccount_metatable[] =
{
    { "deposit", BankAccount_deposit },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

int luaopen_BankAccount(lua_State* L)
{
    luaW_register<BankAccount>(L,
        "BankAccount",
        BankAccount_table,
        BankAccount_metatable,
        BankAccount_new // If your class has a default constructor you can omit this argument,
                        // LuaWrapper will generate a default allocator for you.
    );
    return 1;
}
```

As you can see, Using this method the first argument is an instance of the object

Comment: This is how you wrap a C++ to Lua, you can find many examples on the web. On the other hand a Lua statement `if(type(ba)=="BankAccount')` will still not work

Comment: I got this to work by pushing integers that were typedef'd to other types as my "GID"

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and the way I resolved is:

1) Create an interface class in C++ with abstract methods

```
class LuaInterfaceOOP
{
public:
    LuaInterfaceOOP(){}
    virtual CObject* clone(void) const=0;
    virtual wxString type(void)=0;
    virtual wxString ToString(void)=0;
    wxString GetType()return this->type();
    wxString GetToString() return this->ToString();
    virtual ~CObject(){}
};
```

2) Any class that you want to expose to Lua should implement this to be consistent.

```
class MyClass: public LuaInterfaceOOP
{
 public:
 wxString type() { return "MyClass";}
 wxString ToString();
};
```

3) When you write a wrapper for this class make sure

```
int MyClass_toString(lua_State* L)
{
    MyClass* mc= luaW_check<MyClass>(L, 1);
    const char* str=mc->ToString().c_str();
    lua_pushstring(L, str);

    return 1;
}

int MyClass_type(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_pushstring(L,"MyClass");

    return 1;
}
```

4) Overload the type function provided by Lua, for you the important part will be:

```
case LUA_TUSERDATA:
{
    wxString str1;
    if(lua_getmetatable(L,idx)) // Stk: Userdata Table
    {
        lua_getfield(L,-1,"type");  // Stk: Userdata Table function
        if(!lua_pcall(L,0,1,0))     // Stk: Userdata Table string
        {
            str1<<lua_tostring(L,-1);
            wxReturnStr<<str1;
            lua_pop(L,2);// Stk: Userdata
        }
        else //stk: Userdata table
        {
            lua_pop(L,1);
            wxReturnStr<<"userdata"; //stk: Userdata
        }

    }else wxReturnStr<<"userdata";
    break;
}
```

EDIT 1: Adding code to wrap C++ funcs to Lua

```
static luaL_Reg MyClass_table[] = {
    { NULL, NULL }
};

static luaL_Reg Myclass_metatable[] = {  
    {"type",    Myclass_type},
    {"__tostring",      Myclass_toString},
    { NULL, NULL }
};
```

Finally,

```
static int luaopen_MyClass(lua_State* L)
{
    luaW_register<MyClass>(L, "MyClass", MyClass_table, MyClass_metatable, MyClass_new);
   return 1;
}
```

Now in Lua you can use an expression such as `if(type(aclass)=="MyClass")`

I am not sure if these steps are the best way, but so far it worked.

Comment: What is luaW_check? I can't seem to find it in the lua manual.

Comment: it is from another library, https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapper/src/fd9c4fdbf4b25034e3b8475a2c8da66b7caab427?at=default

Comment: With the library could I just push the entire class into lua? and then it will call back all my C++ functions inside the class relative to the instance? is that how it works?

Comment: Using your structure, is it possible to call MyClass.type()? is the first argument of the member functions an instance of the object itself? similar to lua's self? Sorry if you have already answered my question, I just don't see it yet.

Comment: Ahh yes! I got it! The first argument is an instance of the object! A good example can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapperexample/src/f6958844b60f91ed90d039eabe807522a1b13ba8/example1/?at=default.
Thank you so much!